# Why my pages doesn't exist when i click the button?

Tags: java, android, xml

My problems :

1. My apps doesn't have error.
2. When I click at the button, my page isn't display.
3. It can exist when I click at the certain place not at the button.

I already do refer by youtube, but myself cannot resolve this problem.

This is my java file : 
**dashboard.java**

```
package com.example.whatisthat;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Dashboard extends Activity implements     View.OnClickListener
{

private CardView LoginBtn, CaptureBtn, AboutBtn, FeedbackBtn, IgBtn,     HelpBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    //DEFINE CARDS
    //ADD CLICK LISTENER TO THE CARDS
    LoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.Login);
    LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    CaptureBtn = findViewById(R.id.Capture);
    CaptureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    AboutBtn = findViewById(R.id.About);
    AboutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    FeedbackBtn = findViewById(R.id.Feedback);
    FeedbackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    IgBtn = findViewById(R.id.Ig);
    IgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    HelpBtn = findViewById(R.id.Help);
    HelpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent i;

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Login : i = new Intent(this,Login1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Capture : i = new Intent(this, Capture.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.About : i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Feedback : i = new Intent(this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Ig : i = new Intent(this, Instagram.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Help : i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        default:break;
    }
}
}
```

This is my xml file : 
**activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Dashboard">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#6A287E">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/iconfyp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DASHBOARD"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/Login"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/people"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="LOGIN"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/Capture"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/cameraa"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="CAPTURE"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/About"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/aboutt"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="ABOUT"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/feedback"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="FEEDBACK "
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/Ig"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/instagram"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="INSTAGRAM"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true”
                        android:id="@+id/Help"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/help"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="HELP"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Which button is not working?

Comment: All button isnt working

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Where can I find the answer?

Comment: Below man. Just look down of the page.

Comment: Please consider following the accepted standard of suffixing your activity classes with `Activity` or the appropriate type of class.

Comment: Im just added your code, but doesnt work

Comment: Please stop spamming the same post again and again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `android:clickable="true"` , `android:focusable="true"` and  `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`

```
                   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:focusable="true
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                 // your code
                   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can’t work by added the code

Comment: Is the cardview is clickable?

Comment: Cardview cannot click

Comment: Now check my answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: it just clickable for certain time. When i click it back it doesnt work at all. Why????

Comment: Why it just clickable at Login. For the rest cannot click

Comment: At the 3 lines to every cardview .After that  If it don't clickable then there is problem with your parent .For your parent problem post a new question . So as my method works for your question and  I will ask you not to forget to accept it, by clicking the checkmark (✔️) on the left side under the vote arrows. Should change the color in green. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: If you post a new question about parent give me the in the comment box . I will solve it . Thanks

Comment: I suppose to post dashboard.java & activity_dashboard.xml by title about parent? That right?

Comment: Yes. That's Right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57646168/why-my-button-cannot-function-does-it-problem-at-my-projects-parent