# Cardview Click is not opening Activty

Tags: java, android, xml

My problems :

1. no error in this project, i can run successful.
   [image: screenshot]
2. my button can click at a certain time.
3. when i click it back, it doesn't work at all.
4. i think my problem is near the parent.
5. What's my mistake in my project's parent?

Help me please.

Below is my Java file : **`Dashboard.java`**

```
package com.example.whatisthat;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Dashboard extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{

private CardView LoginBtn, CaptureBtn, AboutBtn, FeedbackBtn, IgBtn,     HelpBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
    //DEFINE CARDS
    //ADD CLICK LISTENER TO THE CARDS
    LoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.Login);
    LoginBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    CaptureBtn = findViewById(R.id.Capture);
    CaptureBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    AboutBtn = findViewById(R.id.About);
    AboutBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    FeedbackBtn = findViewById(R.id.Feedback);
    FeedbackBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    IgBtn = findViewById(R.id.Ig);
    IgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    HelpBtn = findViewById(R.id.Help);
    HelpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent i;

    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.Login : i = new Intent(this,Login1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Capture : i = new Intent(this, Capture.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.About : i = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Feedback : i = new Intent(this, Feedback.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Ig : i = new Intent(this, Instagram.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        case R.id.Help : i = new Intent(this, Help.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
        default:break;
    }
}
}
```

Below is my .xml file : **activity_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Dashboard">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="230dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="#6A287E">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/iconfyp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="DASHBOARD"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="215dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?   android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/Login"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/people"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="LOGIN"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonLogin"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/Capture"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/cameraa"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="CAPTURE"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonCapture"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/About"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/aboutt"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="ABOUT"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonAbout"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/Feedback"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/feedback"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="FEEDBACK "
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonFeedback"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="135dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/Ig"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/instagram"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="INSTAGRAM"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonIg"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                        android:foreground="?    android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:id="@+id/Help"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                                android:layout_height="50dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/help"
                                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="HELP"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                            <Button
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:id="@+id/buttonHelp"
                                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is happening on click. ? Any logs getting generated ?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you have added the clickListener in the CardView and not in the Button. The CardView cannot be clicked as you have set another layout inside it with "match_parent". Therefore, to solve it you have to:
1) add id attribute in you Buttons in xml
2) find them with findViewById() in your activity class
3) Add whatever clickListeners you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well You have to First Remove space from this  `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`  and add this to all the button

`android:clickable="false"`

If you want to Open Activity With `Button` Then you have to put `setOnClickListener` to Button .Else if you want to open Activity with `Cardview` you have to put `setOnClickListener` to cardview.

Use this for `OnClick` Method:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view==LoginBtn){
 startActivity(new Intent(this,Login1.class));
        }else if(view==Capture){
startActivity(new Intent(this,Capture.class));

      }
     //Do rest by yourself.

    }
```

Comment: Already changed. Like before. My button can click at the bottom of the box with a few click. Cannot click at everywhere all the space provided at the box

Comment: Can click at the border of the button. But cannot click at the middle of the box. Nothing happens

Comment: android:clickable="false" add this to all of button .And let me know if it works.

Comment: THANKYOU VERY MUCH SIR, I REALLY APPRECIATE YOU successful, tq again